# How to get a function Return Type as a CodeClass2 from a method CodeElement2

Tags: c#, t4, envdte

Using EnvDTE in a T4 template I can get all methods from a class easily.

Taking it a step further and looping those methods to get the return type as a CodeClass2 (or simply CodeElement2) I get stuck.

```
((CodeFunction2)codeElement).Type.AsFullName;
```

This code works fine getting the return type full name, but if I try this;

```
((CodeFunction2)codeElement).Type as CodeClass2;
```

I get a null value everytime, even though returning the AsFullName works?

I ultimately need to loop the properties of a functions return type object, but failing miserably at this point.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [CodeFunction2.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb6yyh9h.aspx) returns a CodeTypeRef.

So you should be able to use:

```
((CodeFunction2)codeElement).Type.CodeType as CodeClass2;
```

Comment: I was trying this before I posted with the same results.
This was the correct answer Matt, however, where I went wrong was the fact that the return type was a generic.... Doh!

If I ignore generic, in my case IEnumerable<MyObject>, things work.
Now to figure out how to deal with those cases.